# pandas corr and corrwith very slow

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with <30K rows, and 7 columns and I'm trying to get the correlation of 4 of the columns to the fifth one. The problem is, I'd like to do this with massive datasets but this takes ~40s to run. Here is my code:

```
df_a = dfr[['id', 'state', 'perform', 'A']].groupby(['id', 'state']).corr().ix[1::2][['A']].reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis=1)
df_b = dfr[['id', 'state', 'perform', 'B']].groupby(['id', 'state']).corr().ix[1::2][['B']].reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis=1)
df_c = dfr[['id', 'state', 'perform', 'C']].groupby(['id', 'state']).corr().ix[1::2][['C']].reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis=1)
df_d = dfr[['id', 'state', 'perform', 'D']].groupby(['id', 'state']).corr().ix[1::2][['D']].reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis=1)

df = df_a.merge(df_b, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df.merge(df_c, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df.merge(df_d, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Sample data looks as follows:

```
ID   State   perform   A   B   C   D
234   AK     75.8456   1   0   0   0
284   MN     78.6752   0   0   1   0
```

Does anyone have any tips on how I could make this faster, or implement this method better?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure why you're doing all that, what's wrong with `df[cols].corrwith(series)`?

Comment: is your data all floats? try df.dtypes. This is almost immediate on my computer: pandas.np.corrcoef(pandas.np.random.rand(5,30000))

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I'm going through that grouping because my perform column is specific for each grouping, and comparing them all to one Series was also slower. My earlier method was exactly what you said, and that was 12s slower than this method.

My first attempted looked like this:

Comment: @alex314159 Yes all my data is float or int, except for the state column, which is an obj.

Comment: can you link to your data or post a subset of your data so we see what it looks like

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ 
my first attempt looked like this

df = dfr[['id', 'state', 'perform', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D']].groupby(['id', 'state']).corrwith(dfr.perform)

Comment: @alex314159 I edited my question to include data sample!

Comment: @TylerMarques this may not make your code run faster but you should avoid using `.ix` as it is deprecated. Use `.loc` or `iloc` instead.

Second, is your sample data from `df` or `dfr`?

Comment: Third, change `.reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis = 1)` to `.reset_index(2, drop = True)`. Does the same thing with one less chained function.

Comment: @IanThompson thank you for the input, I changed those two things, speed is actually slightly slower with `.iloc` vs `.ix` but that is okay, better than using a deprecated method.

Comment: @TylerMarques did you switch the `merge` to `pd.concat`? That might speed it up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163257/discussion-between-ian-thompson-and-tyler-marques).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While probably not the best solution, this worked for me and brought run time down to a total of 4.8 s vs the previous 52s.

I ended up grouping in pandas, then running the correlation using numpy.

```
groups = df.groupby(['course_id', 'activity_id'])
np_arr = []

for (cor_id,act_id), group in groups:

    np_arr.append([cor_id, act_id,
                   np.corrcoef(group.A.as_matrix(), group.perform.as_matrix())[0,1],
                   np.corrcoef(group.B.as_matrix(), group.perform.as_matrix())[0,1],
                   np.corrcoef(group.C.as_matrix(), group.perform.as_matrix())[0,1],
                   np.corrcoef(group.D.as_matrix(), group.perform.as_matrix())[0,1]])

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.array(np_arr), columns=['course_id', 'activity_id', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

This was effective at reducing my runtime, and I am going to type my variables using cython to further increase speed.

Answer (score 10):

The reason pandas corr is **very slow** is that it considers NANs: it is basically a cython for-loop.

If your data doesn't have NANs, numpy.corrcoef is *much faster*.

Answer (score 6):

I want to second ma-ming's answer here...

numpy is incredibly fast relative to pandas. I was doing a little testing to see just how much faster... **MASSIVE speed increases**:

```
import timeit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


holdings_array = np.arange(40, 100, 20)
dates_array = [200, 800]

calc = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
        [['Correlation', 'Returns'], ['pandas', 'numpy', 'pandas.values'], dates_array],
        names=['Method', 'Library', 'Shape']),
    columns=holdings_array
).unstack(level=-1)

print("Checking pandas vs numpy... (ms)")

# PANDAS
for num_holdings in holdings_array:
    for num_dates in dates_array:
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=[num_dates, num_holdings]))
        ls = np.random.random(size=num_holdings)
        calc.loc[('Correlation', 'pandas'), (num_holdings, num_dates)] \
            = str(np.round(timeit.timeit('df.corr()', number=100, globals=globals()) * 10, 3))
        calc.loc[('Returns', 'pandas'), (num_holdings, num_dates)] \
            = str(np.round(timeit.timeit('(df*ls).sum(axis=1)', number=100, globals=globals()) * 10, 3))


# # NUMPY
# for x, num_holdings in enumerate(holdings_array):
#     for y, num_dates in enumerate(dates_array):
#         df = np.array(np.random.random(size=[num_dates, num_holdings]))
#         ls = np.random.random(size=num_holdings)
#         calc.loc[('Correlation', 'numpy'), (num_holdings, num_dates)] \
#             = str(np.round(timeit.timeit('np.corrcoef(df)', number=100, globals=globals()) * 10, 3))
#         calc.loc[('Returns', 'numpy'), (num_holdings, num_dates)] \
#             = str(np.round(timeit.timeit('(df*ls).sum(axis=1)', number=100, globals=globals()) * 10, 3))

# PANDAS.VALUES WITH NP FUNCTIONS
for num_holdings in holdings_array:
    for num_dates in dates_array:
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=[num_dates, num_holdings]))
        ls = np.random.random(size=num_holdings)
        calc.loc[('Correlation', 'pandas.values'), (num_holdings, num_dates)] \
            = str(np.round(timeit.timeit('np.corrcoef(df.values, rowvar=False)', number=100, globals=globals()) * 10, 3))
        calc.loc[('Returns', 'pandas.values'), (num_holdings, num_dates)] \
            = str(np.round(timeit.timeit('(df.values*ls).sum(axis=1)', number=100, globals=globals()) * 10, 3))

print(f"Results: \n{calc.to_string()}")
```

**Whenever possible, if are doing vector calculations on a pandas df, change it to df.values and run the np operation instead**

For example, I could change the df.corr() to np.corrcoef(df.values, rowvar=False) (note: rowvar=False important so shape is correct) and for large operations you will see 10x, 100x speeds. Not trivial.

[image]

Comment: I ended up finding exactly what you put here, using `pandas` was just impossible, it was much much slower and I was forced to utilize `numpy`. The time savings are non-trivial with very little code change.

Comment: Thanks JBB and Ma Ming for suggesting the numpy. I was working with (800000 X 2354). .corr() never finished for me but np.corrcoef(df.values, rowvar=False) finished in 15 secs. Legend!

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick comparison between your original code and my code, here are the time differences:

## Your Code

```
%%timeit

# data
'''
ID   State   perform   A   B   C   D
234   AK     75.8456   1   0   0   0
284   MN     78.6752   0   0   1   0
'''

# make dataframe
dfr = pd.read_clipboard()

df_a = dfr[['ID', 'State', 'perform', 'A']].groupby(['ID', 'State']).corr().ix[1::2][['A']].reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis=1)
df_b = dfr[['ID', 'State', 'perform', 'B']].groupby(['ID', 'State']).corr().ix[1::2][['B']].reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis=1)
df_c = dfr[['ID', 'State', 'perform', 'C']].groupby(['ID', 'State']).corr().ix[1::2][['C']].reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis=1)
df_d = dfr[['ID', 'State', 'perform', 'D']].groupby(['ID', 'State']).corr().ix[1::2][['D']].reset_index(2).drop('level_2', axis=1)

df = df_a.merge(df_b, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df.merge(df_c, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df.merge(df_d, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

[image: your time]

## My Code

```
%%timeit

# data
'''
ID   State   perform   A   B   C   D
234   AK     75.8456   1   0   0   0
284   MN     78.6752   0   0   1   0
'''

# make dataframe
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# make other dfs
df_a = df.loc[:, :'A'].groupby([
    'ID',
    'State'
]).corr().iloc[1::2][['A']].reset_index(2, drop = True)

df_b = df.loc[:, [
    'ID',
    'State',
    'perform',
    'B'
]].groupby([
    'ID',
    'State'
]).corr().iloc[1::2][['B']].reset_index(2, drop = True)

df_c = df.loc[:, [
    'ID',
    'State',
    'perform',
    'C'
]].groupby([
    'ID',
    'State'
]).corr().iloc[1::2][['C']].reset_index(2, drop = True)

df_d = df.loc[:, [
    'ID',
    'State',
    'perform',
    'D'
]].groupby([
    'ID',
    'State'
]).corr().iloc[1::2][['D']].reset_index(2, drop = True)

# concat them together
pd.concat([df_a, df_b, df_c, df_d], axis = 1)
```

[image: my time]

The difference may still be negligible though.

## Edit

Decided to try using a `for` loop to remove repeated code. Showed some improvement in run time:

```
%%timeit

# data
'''
ID   State   perform   A   B   C   D
234   AK     75.8456   1   0   0   0
284   MN     78.6752   0   0   1   0
'''

# make dataframe
df = pd.read_clipboard()

# make list of letter columns
letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# store corr() dfs in list for concatenation
list_of_dfs = []
for letter in letters:
    list_of_dfs.append(df.loc[:, [
        'ID',
        'State',
        'perform',
        letter
    ]].groupby([
        'ID',
        'State'
    ]).corr().iloc[1::2][[letter]].reset_index(2, drop = True))

# concat them together
pd.concat(list_of_dfs, axis = 1)
```

[image: edited output]

Comment: I appreciate the try, but that doesn't run much quicker on my machine. I did use your suggestions from your other comments though!

Comment: last thing I can think of - can you try with a subset of your data? Say 500 rows and measure how long it takes? If 30,000 rows takes much longer than 30,000/500 * that time, it might be a memory problem and you want to process the data in chunks.

Comment: @alex314159 Thanks for the suggestion, but I believe it was something with pandas, as I've rewritten my function to use numpy to do the correlation and it's much faster.